# Is it possible to query a fusion table with the row layout filters applied

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I am returning an entire table as a JSON call, no problem. without things like Stored Procs,  I see the row/car layouts as the only filtering mechanism... is it possible to query the filtered row layout (ex: 1HqI7qIUMB-_52YHwWULUkF5LrnM5Ocp5OlYOiwQ#rows:id=5)? I can, of course, apply the same filters in the SQL WHERE claus... but why if i dont have to? When i apply the "#rows:id=5" on my current query, nothing is returned.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no way to get at the filters in a particular row layout via the API; you'll just have to replicate the SQL as you say. It's an interesting idea, though, so I'd recommend filing a feature request with the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/fusion-tables/).

Rod